# Hive: dividing STRING with delimiters

Tags: sql, string, hive

I have to divide a STRING value with the "." delimiter into two values. Like this:

> input:

| var0 |
| --- |
| 9342102124501.0000001236 |

> output:

| var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- |
| 9342102124501 | 0000001236 |

I know it's easy, but I completely don't understand regular expressions..

Comment: please make/share an attempt before asking for help? Do you need to use regex?

Comment: to my mind regexp is the way, but perhaps there can be some other solutions

Comment: make life simple, avoid reg EX :) @gmb's answer is best because you can extract as many dot delimited strings as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [string-function `split`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions), which accepts a regex and returns an array:

```
select var0,
    split(var0, '[\.]')[0] as var1,
    split(var0, '[\.]')[1] as var2
from mytable
```

Comment: thank you, this works! just to add: i've checked the manual on "split" function and found out that in this example split can also be rewritten like this: split(var0, '\\.')[0]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `substr` and `instr` :

```
select 
  substr(var0, 1, instr(var0,'.')-1) as va1, 
  substr(var0, instr(var0,'.')+1) as var2
from mytable ;
```